# Bluemixでアプリを別のスペースに移すには？

Tags: bluemix

デプロイして稼動中のアプリをスペース間で移動することはできますか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bluemixはアプリを移動するという機能自体は提供していません。
しかし元のアプリを削除しデプロイ先を切り替えて別のスペースにpushすることで、実質的に移動と同じことは可能です。cfコマンドを並べてスクリプトを作れば、この移動処理を一気に実行することもできます。

Answer (score 1):

FYI ですが、最近 cf copy-source コマンドが追加されました。

```
$ cf copy-source --help
NAME:
   copy-source - Make a copy of app source code from one application to another.  Unless overridden, the copy-source command will restart the application.

USAGE:
      cf copy-source SOURCE-APP TARGET-APP [-o TARGET-ORG] [-s TARGET-SPACE] [--no-restart]


OPTIONS:
   -o                Org that contains the target application
   -s                Space that contains the target application
   --no-restart      Override restart of the application in target environment after copy-source completes
```

この場合、手元にソースがなくても space間でアプリケーションがコピーできます。なお、ソースの取得は
cf-download プラグインが便利です。

https://github.com/ibmjstart/cf-download