# Bluemix、米国DCでつくった環境を、英国DCに移せますか？

Tags: bluemix, softlayer

IBMのPaaSであるBluemixでアプリケーション開発をしているものです。

Bluemixは「米国南部」と「英国」のふたつのデータセンターを選んで使うことができます。たとえば「米国南部」のデータセンターでつくった環境を「英国」に移すことはできるのでしょうか？

ご存知の方、ご教示いただけると助かります。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

[こちら](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/12714/bluemix%E3%81%A7%E3%82%A2%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA%E3%82%92%E5%88%A5%E3%81%AE%E3%82%B9%E3%83%9A%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9%E3%81%AB%E7%A7%BB%E3%81%99%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF)と同様のご質問ですね。環境を別の地域に移動するという機能自体はありませんが、地域を切り替えてデプロイし直してください。
ただし、サービスについては地域によって提供される内容が一部異なりますので、[こちら](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/services.html)の「地域別のサービス」の表でご確認ください。